# How to only produce one answer in slot machine without the other answer also popping up?

Tags: java

beginner at java here so go easy on me haha. Im creating a simple 3 number slot machine that first prompts the user if they would like to play. The user types in a positive number to play then it brings up 3 random numbers assigned to a slot number. If the user matches 2 numbers it says "Matched 2!" and if the user matches all three it says "Jackpot!" My issue at the moment is that when the user gets a jackpot, it still says "Matched 2!" just below "Jackpot!" How would I make it so when the user gets a jackpot it just doesn't even check for matching 2 and goes on with the loop?

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SlotMachine{

public static void main(String []args){

Random rnd = new Random();
Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
  int slot1;
  int slot2;
  int slot3;
  int play;

  String input;
 //end of variables


System.out.println("Play the simple slot machine. To continue \nplaying enter ANY positive number. To stop \nplaying enter a negative 1.");
System.out.println("Wanna play? :");
  input = key.nextLine();
  play = Integer.parseInt(input);
while (play > 0) {

slot1 = rnd.nextInt(3);
slot2 = rnd.nextInt(3);
slot3 = rnd.nextInt(3);


System.out.println("Slot 1: " + slot1 + "\tSlot 2: " + slot2 + "\tSlot 3: " + slot3);

     if (slot1 == slot2 && slot2 == slot3) {

     System.out.println("Jackpot!");

}//Checking to see if all 3 slots match and returning a Jackpot!


    if (slot1 == slot2 || slot2 == slot3 || slot1 == slot3) {

System.out.println("Matched 2!");
}//Checking to see if any 2 slots match


System.out.println("Wanna play?");
input = key.nextLine();
play = Integer.parseInt(input);



if (play == -1) {

System.out.println("Thanks for playing!");

}//end if -1



}

}//end main

}//end class
```

Comment: Use an `if-else if` chain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the logic you're using to check for winners. Instead of using several if statements, you need to use if-else statements. The main difference being that if-else statements only allows the first true statement to execute and skips the rest.

```
// check if all three numbers match, if this is true the else-if is skipped
if (slot1 == slot2 && slot2 == slot3) {
    System.out.println("Jackpot!");

// check if two numbers match
} else if (slot1 == slot2 || slot2 == slot3 || slot1 == slot3) {
    System.out.println("Matched 2!");
}
```